# How do i update my code base in git without having to delete, stash or checkin my current changes?

Tags: git, mercurial

My team just moved our project from mercurial to git and I'm still getting used to the workflow. When we used mercurial my flow would look like this:

- write some code
- hg pull
- hg update
- resolve any merge conflicts
- continue writting code, repeating the above steps until finished
- hg pull (and resolve all conflicts)
- hg commit (or add) with a message
- hg push

Essentially, write code, pull occasionally to keep myself synched, commit when i'm done.

With git I can't seem to pull after I've written code. When I run 'git pull' I get the following error message:
'error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:...Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.'

I'm hesitant to commit my changes, because at this point in my flow they are almost never finished enough for me to want to commit. **Is there a way for me to pull the updated changes and apply them without wiping out or stashing my own? If not, how can i adapt my old workflow to the git model?**

Comment: If you pull changes that conflict with your local changes, what behavior do you expect/want?  That might help in giving you a better answer.

Comment: @larsks I would expect changes that don't conflict to apply, and when conflicts do occour, i would expect a merge to be attempted, possibly resulting in a partially broken file that prompts me to manually merge  (usually this means markers like <<<<<<<local and then >>>>other to dileniate where my code and the unmergable new changes are)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make a "temporary" commit:

```
# Possibly: git add any untracked new files
git commit -am "INTERIM commit - WIP"
# need "rebase" here, because we want to discard
# our temporary commit later
git pull --rebase 
# resolve any possible conflicts
git reset HEAD~1 # throw away interim commit, keep changes
```

Many people are hesitant to commit something which is "unfinished". In git, commits are so incredibly quick and cheap that there's no reason for that feeling. Just make a temp commit, then throw it away.

And if you pull new changes frequently, consider `git pull --rebase` (maybe even make it the default) - that way you don't get a merge commit for every pull, which just messes up history.

Note: In the example I gave, you must use the `--rebase` option for the pull, because otherwise the temp commit cannot be discarded (because it will become one parent of the merge commit). There are others ways to solve this, but this is the simplest (to me).

Comment: Note that the same remarks also go for Mercurial:

- Commits are cheap (and it's possible to use 'hg commit --amend')
- Consider using rebase

Answer (score 2):

One might argue that a merge with uncommitted content is more problematic if it succeeds than if it fails.

Seems to me you either want to commit your work in its current state or you don't.

If you don't want to commit it, then the merge should be with a clean checkout of your committed tip -- so you should stash your current work, do and record the merge correctly, then have stash pop merge the stashed changes back into your worktree.  Now you have the worktree you're asking for and also a correctly-recorded merge commit, with the merge parents correctly recording the merged history.

If you do want to commit your work in its current state, commit it. Then merge. Now your repo has the same features as above: a correctly-recorded merge commit *and* a correctly-merged worktree.

So, thinking about that, I think I'll go one step further than the hypothetical and say the way to adapt is to adopt.

Answer (score 1):

Best choice for you may be

- Continue to use Mercurial locally
- Use Hg-git to get interoperability with remote Git repo - with your old goodworkflow

You'll be free from brainlesses of Git, and pull with any new changesets in it just (create|add changesets to) anonymous branch in you branch (with your still local commits) without touching your line of history. You can inspect|merge heads later, when it will be needed